# How to draw a graph with X-axis group by and Y-axis a Customized field using MS Project?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I am unable to draw a **chart** in report using MS Project 2013, that have in X-axis (Grouped by) and in the other part Y-axis a **customized field** ?

---

I can't find customized fields here :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it it was in `Number > Custom > Number 1 ..`